# Query user by code and id parameters found in set password path OR custom reset password path

Tags: users, query, password, activation, verification

Is there any way to query users using the parameters of **set password** URLs?  I need to distinguish between the very first activation (welcome) email and reset password email because their corresponding custom forms are presented differently.  Or is there a different config for password resets other than the `setPasswordPath` setting?

e.g. https://some.url/set-password/?code=XXX&id=YYY -> something like:

```
$user = User::find()->verificationCode('XXX')->anyStatus()->one();
$user = Craft::$app->users->getUserByCode('XXX');
```

Knowing the user `status` at the very least would indicate whether they are activating their account or resetting their password.

More details around the workflow.

1. Users are created programatically and sent an activation email to create a password using `getUsers()->sendActivationEmail`
2. Users open the link from the email and set their password via a custom welcome form
3. Users later request a password reset link via a custom password reset form
4. Users open the link but it is structured the same as step 2.

How can I have different links for steps 2 and 4.  As far as I've dug, the only path that can be customized in `general.php` is `setPasswordPath`.